`ld` says `undefined reference` for templated library
I'm trying to create a templated C++ library. The header file of the library is as follows:
// header.h
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
        private:
                T value;
        
        public:
                MyClass(): value(0) {};
                void set(T v);
                void print();
};

The implementation of the library source code is this:
// lib.cc
#include <header.h>

template<typename T>
void MyClass<T>::set(T v)
{
        this->value = v;
}


template<typename T>
void MyClass<T>::print()
{
        std::cout << this->value << std::endl;
}

And the code which uses this library is this:
// test.cc
#include <header.h>

int main()
{
        MyClass<int> obj;
        obj.set(10);
        obj.print();
        return 0;
}

I'm compiling my code using g++ via g++ -I. lib.cc test.cc. Moreover, all the three files are in the same directory. However, when I try to compile my code, I get the following linker errors:
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccbvMPJe.o: in function `main':
test.cc:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `MyClass<int>::set(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cc:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `MyClass<int>::print()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Why can't the linker find the implementations of set and print. It should be able to find the implementation of these two functions in the lib.cc file. What am I doing wrong?

You need to implement your entire class template in the header file.

Is there any other way? I want to keep my header file free of implementation details. I just want to use it as a reference for what all classes are supported and the functions that each class supports

Not really. The compiler needs to have the entire definition of the class template in order to instantiate a class from it.

One way around it is the "Alternative Solution" of this answer but that will restrict the types you can use with your header to the ones you selected to instanciate.

Thanks for the comments. It seems like there is no good way to do what I want to do. I'll just put the class definition in the header itself.

@Setu "I want to keep my header file free of implementation details" -- Not exactly the same thing, but see Is #include'ing .cpp template implementation files a bad practice? (Short answer: use .impl, .ipp, or .tcc instead of .cpp.)
